# using root directory string

Tags: c#

So, i am using the code as follows to find out the current windows "main drive"

```
string rootDrive = Path.GetPathRoot(Environment.SystemDirectory);   
string path =@"c:\Users\Perry Craft\Desktop\password.txt";
Console.WriteLine("Windows is installed on the " + rootDrive + " drive");
if (!File.Exists(@"C: \Users\%username%\Desktop"))
```

what I am trying to do is replace the c in "c:\" with the string value of rootDrive so that even if the windows drive is J:\ it would use that character and be able to save to the users desktop. Do I need to parse the rootDrive string somehow or am i wrong in my thinking that all I should have to do is re write it to say .

```
string rootDrive = Path.GetPathRoot(Environment.SystemDirectory);
string path =@"rootDrive:\Users\Perry Craft\Desktop\password.txt";
```

Answer (score 4):

If you need the desktop directory, interrogate [`Environment.GetFolderPath`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/14tx8hby(v=vs.110).aspx) to get it directly. There is no assurance that the user's desktop is located on `X:\Users\%username%\desktop` (where *X* is the System volume); it is, in fact, entirely [possible](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/kb/949977) for Windows and User Profile directories to be located on different volumes.

For instance, to retrieve the path to `password.txt` on the desktop, use:

```
string desktoppath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.DesktopDirectory);
string path = Path.Combine(desktoppath, "password.txt");
```

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with simple string concatenation:

```
string path = rootDrive + @"Users\Perry Craft\Desktop\password.txt";
```